# Aggregate based on value of a different column

Tags: pandas

I would like to aggregate the sum of `source_bytes` if `destination_port` is `80` into a separate column called `source_bytes_port_80`

My dataframe

```
date                | source_ip     | destination_ip| source_bytes  | destination_port
2020-11-13 13:57:51 | 192.168.1.1   | 10.0.0.1      | 5             | 80
2020-11-13 13:57:51 | 192.168.1.2   | 10.0.0.1      | 1             | 2200  
2020-11-13 13:57:52 | 10.0.0.1      | 192.168.1.1   | 2             | 80
2020-11-13 13:59:53 | 192.168.1.1   | 192.168.1.2   | 3             | 443
2020-11-13 13:59:54 | 192.168.1.1   | 192.168.1.2   | 3             | 1100
```

I was thinking of creating a separate function and then call it with `.agg({'source_bytes':[sum_of_port]})` but I am not sure how I can check the condition inside the function.

Comment: Could you please post how the expected output should look like?

Answer (score 0):

```
df.groupby("desination_port")["source_bytes"].sum()
```

Will give you the sum for each destination_port.   Then add it back into the file as you would like it.